# How to define ASP.NET Core view engines root path?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I try to render section

```
 @RenderSection("/Views/Home/Header.cshtml",false)
```

but view is not found. I don't understand logic of mapping site root to view engine. ASP.NET Core has a lot of site roots, in my case this is not a default project and all of this path is different, for example

```
 ContentRootPath: G:\Projects\Max\FrontEnd\FrontEndCode\
 StaticFilesRoot: G:\Projects\FrontEndTst\FrontEndRoot
 WebRootPath: null
 WebRootFileProvider: Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.CompositeFileProvider
```

`RazorViewEngineOptions` is correct, view name is correct, but view engine can not find my view.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The layout page '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml' cannot find the section '/Views/Home/Header.cshtml' in the content page '/Views/Home/Index.cshtml'.

Maybe I need to add something additional options or something attributes to page. But what?

[image: Source code]

The same result with Html.PartialAsync

[image: PartialAsync]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the `@RenderSection()` method.

[image: RenderSection]

When you use `@RenderSection("/Views/Home/Header.cshtml",false)` in your Layout, The project will find if there is any Section named `/Views/Home/Header.cshtml`  then add it into layout instead of following this root to loading view. `/Views/Home/Header.cshtml`  is a name not a root when in @RenderSection, So you can't use it to load View.

If you want to load view in Layout, I suggest you to use [Partival View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0), If there is a lot of logic in the view you want to load, you can use [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Thank you, moving view to /Home and replace to Html.PartialAsync solve my problem